# Spring Boot não reconhece o controller quando enviada uma requisição com parâmetros

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-boot

O Spring Boot não reconhece meu controler se eu enviar mais parâmetros na requisição. Por exemplo:

Se eu envio uma requisição GET normal o spring boot reconhece meu controller:
`http://localhost/idp/oauth/123/authorize`

Se eu envio uma requisição GET com mais parâmetros na query o spring boot não reconhece meu controller:
`http://localhost/idp/oauth/123/authorize?scope=public_profile`

Eu preciso receber a requisição exatamente conforme o segundo exemplo (com o parametro scope). O spring não reconhece o controller e redireciona para /error.

código:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/idp/oauth")
public class OAuthController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{clientId}/authorize", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String authorizeGet(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            @PathVariable String clientId,
            Model model) {
            // ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{clientId}/authorize", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String authorizePost(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, 
            @PathVariable String clientId,
            Model model) {
            // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está no Stackoverflow em Português, traduza sua pergunta de acordo

Comment: Corrigido, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Bom Dia,

Pelo que eu entendi, falta um atributo no seu método:

```
(@RequestParam(value="scope", defaultValue="public_profile") String scope)
```

Dai sim, você consegue fazer essa query na URL.

Comment: Mesmo adicionando o '@RequestParam(name = "scope") String scope' não funciona :(. Continua redirecionando para o erro.

Comment: qual erro que está dando pra você?

Comment: Eu tenho um interceptador que intercepta todas as requisições. Dai eu vejo a URL requisitada 'System.out.println(request.getRequestURL().toString());' e ele pega http://localhost/error

Comment: dá uma olhada no seu interceptador ou posta ele aqui, eu subi seu código aqui sem interceptador e rolou essa chamada : localhost:8380/idp/oauth/200/authorize?scope=public_profile

Answer (score 0):

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/{clientId}/authorize")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authorizeGet(
                @RequestParam(value = "scope", defaultValue = "public_profile") String scope) {
    // ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Falta você adicionar o @QueryParam nos parametros que você está passando via Query. Que é o caso do "?scope=public_profile"